# objects, inheritance and list-property doesn´t work

Tags: c#, inheritance

I´m new to OO ... till now I worked with VB6.
I have a class:

```
public class clocation_base
{
    public clocation_base() 
    {
    }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 ImagesCurrent { get; set; }
    public Int32 ImagesTotal { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ImagesLastUpload { get; set; }
    public decimal Lon { get; set; }
    public decimal Lat { get; set; }
    public int DistanceInMeter { get; set; }
    public int Proofed { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string PreviewImg1 { get; set; }
    public string PreviewImg2 { get; set; }
    public string PreviewImg3 { get; set; }
    public string PreviewImg4 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to "extend" this class with a list (another class).
This is my "list:

```
public class clocation_media
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

I would now "extend" my clocation_base with the media-list:

```
public class clocation_extended : clocation_base
{
    List<clocation_media> media { get; set; }
    public clocation_extended()
    {
        media = new List<clocation_media>();
    }
}
```

In my code I use:

```
clocation_extended mTest = new clocation_extended();
mTest.Name = "Locationname";
```

Now I want to use:

```
mTest.media.Add("http://contoso.com/img1.jpg", "Image", null);
```

But this doesn´t work.

`mTest.media...` isn´t there ...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Change `List<clocation_media> media { get; set; }` to `public List<clocation_media> media { get; set; }`

Comment: Please use the [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx). This will make it easier for others (and maybe yourself) to read your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

class members are private by default in C#, so you have to make `media` public.

```
public class clocation_extended : clocation_base
{
    public List<clocation_media> media { get; set; }
    public clocation_extended()
    {
        media = new List<clocation_media>();
    }
}
```

---

Also note that

```
mTest.media.Add("http://contoso.com/img1.jpg", "Image", null);
```

will not work, since `media` is of type `List<clocation_media>`, so you have to add an instance of `clocation_media`:

```
var media = new clocation_media
{
    Type = "Image",
    URL = "http://contoso.com/img1.jpg"
};

mTest.media.Add(media);
```

Comment: Wow. Simple. Cool. Can you provide a snippet, how to get `mTest.media.Add("http://contoso.com/img1.jpg", "Image", null);` to work, too ?

Answer (score 0):

The `List<clocation_media> media { get; set; }` must be set `public`, otherwise you cannot access it from outside the class. Members in C# classes are `private` by default. You must specify an accessor, if you want something else than `private`.